# How to make the second element appear after the first one has disappeared?

Tags: css

I want to make the first square appear after 3s and then it needs to disappear. After it disappears, the second square becomes visible after 11s. How to make the second square appear only after the first one has disappeared after 11 seconds?

```css
.one, .two{
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
}

.one{
  animation: fadein 3s, fadeout 7s ;
}


.two{
  animation: fadein 11s, fadeout 17s ;
}



@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
     <div class="one"></div>
          <br>
       <div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: Can't you just use animation-delay: 11s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `animation-delay` maybe?

Also note that you cannot animate the same css attribute in multiple keyframes on the same element. The css defined in the last keyframe will always override the earlier ones. You can try to use % to achieve something similar to what you want.

```css
.one, .two{
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.one{
  animation: fadeinout1 10s;
}

.two{
  animation: fadeinout2 28s ;
  animation-delay: 10s ;
}

@keyframes fadeinout1 {
  0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  30% { opacity: 1; } /*Simulate 3s, out of the whole animation of 10s*/
}

@keyframes fadeinout2 {
  0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  39% { opacity: 1; } /*Simulate 11s, out of the whole animation of 28s*/
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
    <br>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: /* Thank you for extra explanation in comments */